# Need some light on PayPal's Website Payments Pro

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

After having a good read through PayPal's docs, I'm still lost.

FYI in Canada and US it's called "Website Payments Pro", otherwise it's "PayPal Payments Pro".

I need to setup a way of:

1. User subscribing to a yearly fee
2. **User can setup subscriptions WITHOUT a paypal account (pro feature)**

This sounds really simple, but when you start searching for more technical docs about that matter I can only find articles like these:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-recurring-payments/

Which is fine, but this isn't for PayPal Payments Pro. I heard I'll have to use server-side calls to the API but all I can find is people telling me to "create a button".

But the buttons, for some reason, doesn't support Pro features and ask users to register on PayPal to get subscribed which my client doesn't want at all.

Could anyone share me some light about those?

I find PayPal's docs misleading. I really really need to get this done as soon as possible but I cannot seem to find good docs or a good working example for this.

Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Payments Pro is the new name for Website Payments Pro. The button way of doing things is called PayPal Payments Standard.

See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/. Recurring payments can be set up with ExpressCheckout (buyer has a paypal account and logs in to paypal site to approve subscription during setup) or DoDirectPayment (you provide buyer's credit card info when setting up the subscription)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it, but if you don't want to mess around with API calls, then I would suggest using a subscription button and signing up for Enhanced Recurring Payments.  This allows you to accept subscriptions from buyers who don't have a PayPal account and don't want to sign up for one.  To sign up, go to https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/merchant/ERPOverview.